# Dplyr: How to match a value from multiple columns?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have a dataset with *N* column and an additional one containing a number of column. I want to add another column which will return values taken from a column having a particular number (rowwise).

| Col 1 | … | Col 14 | … | Col *n* | Number of column | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | … | a14 | … | an | 14 | a14 |
| b1 | … | b14 | … | bn | 8 | b8 |
| c1 | … | c14 | … | cn | 1 | c1 |

**Such operation can be done with a *for* loop, but how it can be done in *dplyr*?** Thank you!

Comment: If you reshape the data long and filter that, you could join the output to your original dataframe. Would it be possible to include sample data in the form of code so that we could try out solutions on something more tangible?

Answer (score 1):

Base R option -

```
df$Value <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), df$n)]
df

#  col1 col2 col3 n Value
#1    1    6   11 1     1
#2    2    7   12 2     7
#3    3    8   13 3    13
#4    4    9   14 3    14
#5    5   10   15 2    10
```

In `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Value = c_across()[n])
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10, col3 = 11:15, n = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2))
```